# How do I paste text at multi-line selection in vi?

Tags: vim, vi

I know how to use this with manual typing:

Use Ctrl+V to enter visual block mode
Move Up/Downto select the columns of text in the lines you want to comment.
Then hit Shift+i and type the text you want to insert.
Then hit Esc, wait 1 second and the inserted text will appear on every line.

But i don't want to want type the text. **I want just to paste it**.. (because is a long string..)

Thanks, Mor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you are in insert mode (after `I`), you can press `<C-r>"` to insert the content of the default register or `<C-r>a` for register `a` to `z`.

You can also use completion in that context: `<C-n>` for example.

Answer (score 1):

If the text you want to use is in a register, use [`<c-r>` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>)](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-R). So, after you press `I`, instead of typing, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, and the register name you want.

Since the OS clipboard is in [the `+` register](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/96/205), you would do: `<c-r>+` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>).